# Filling the FLOAT Gap Using Dots or Underlines

Tags: html, css

I use `<span>` to left-right align some items as follows—similar to `\hfill` in LaTeX.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<div style="width:1024px;margin:auto">
HELLO<span style="float:right">WORLD</span>
</div>
</html>
```

This leaves a white gap between `HELLO` and `WORLD`. Can this gap be filled with dots or underlines—similarly to `\dotfill` or `\hfill` in LaTeX?

Before filling just the gap, I first tried to underline the entire part using `<u>` in this way.

```
<u>HELLO<span style="float:right">WORLD</span></u>
```

This way did not continue after the `HELLO` at the beginning. If the `<u>` is applied inside the `<span>`, then this `<u>` only underlines the encapsulated `WORLD` at the end. I wonder whether `<u>` can be applied to the white gap without repeating `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use flexbox rather than `float` and then a pseudo-element with a suitably styled repeating gradient as the "line".

```css
:root {
  --h: 2px;
  --w: 10px;
  --c: black;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

span:before {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 .25em;
  height: var(--h);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--c), var(--c) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent 100%);
  background-size: var(--w) var(--h);
}

.red {
  --c: red;
  --h: 3px;
  --w: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  HELLO<span>WORLD</span>
</div>

<div>
  GOODBYE<span class="red">CRUEL WORLD</span>
</div>
```